# Can't call an initializer method in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call the method `fillList()` to fill an `ArrayList`. But it says

> invalid method declaration, return type required.

Methods that are void do not need a return type though. The Semester class I have only contains setters and getters.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<String> termList = new ArrayList<>();
    fillList();
    //Spinner
    Spinner spin = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void fillList(){
        termList.clear();
        //Create term and fill into arraylist
        Semester x = new Semester();
        x.setSemester("Fall");
        termList.add(x.getSemester());
        x = new Semester();
        x.setSemester("Winter");
        termList.add(x.getSemester());
        x = new Semester();
        x.setSemester("Spring");
        termList.add(x.getSemester());
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to be working" As it stands that won't even compile...

Comment: What exactly happens when you try calling it?

Comment: What are you expecting and what is happening?

Comment: it says:

invalid method declaration, required a return type

Comment: call it in constructor

Comment: you only declare the variables in the class. all the others are in the onCreate(). termList = new ArrayList<>();  fillList(); spin = findViewById(R.id.spinner); goe inside the onCreate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a method in the declaration section of your class. You cannot do that unless it returns some value and you are assigning it to one of your variable.

To call a method with void return type or just call a method without using its return value, you should call it inside another method such as `onCreate`

Or you can use an initializer block!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
List< String > termList = new ArrayList<>();
Spinner spin;
{
    fillList();
}
//other declarations and methods.
```

Also you can call the method `findViewById` only after calling the method `setContentView`

So inside onCreate, use:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
spin = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

Answer (score 1):

- You should call `fillList` method in `onCreate` method .
- Add `findViewById` should call after `setContentView` .And it must use when the `Activity` was create .

So change to this .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fillList();
    Spinner spin = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
}
```

**Note**

- Global variables can be used directly in a class, but the method must be used within the method
- The ·findViewById· method must be used after the activity is created, and must be within the activity life cycle method .

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Can you please explain it more?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<String> termList;
    Spinner spin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        termList = new ArrayList<>();
        spin = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        fillList();
    }



    private void fillList(){
        termList.clear();
        //Create term and fill into arraylist
        Semester x = new Semester();
        x.setSemester("Fall");
        termList.add(x.getSemester());
        x = new Semester();
        x.setSemester("Winter");
        termList.add(x.getSemester());
        x = new Semester();
        x.setSemester("Spring");
        termList.add(x.getSemester());
    }

}
```